# from an IMG TAG to a FILE INPUT

Tags: javascript, croppie

I have an image with base64 url as src. I would like to send this image to the server using an input file (with a form).
So, i need to convert an img tag to an input file.

I am using the plugin Croppie to crop an image. Then, the result is writen in an img tag.

I have tried to convert the img tag into a File. But then i dont know how to convert the file to an input file.

```
<div>
    <label for="img">Image</label><input type="file" name="img" id="img" value=""/>
</div>
<div>
    <img id="outImg" />
    <input type="file" name="imgtbn" id="imgtbn" value=""/>
</div>



 document.getElementById('img').onchange = function (evt) {
    var output = document.getElementById('outImg');
    output.src = URL.createObjectURL(evt.target.files[0]);


    if(this.c!=undefined)
    {
        this.c.destroy();
    }
    var el = document.getElementById('outImg');
    this.c = new Croppie(el, {
        viewport: { width: 300, height: 300 },
        boundary: { width: 900, height: 300 },
        showZoomer: false,
        enableOrientation: true,
        update: function (data) {
            this.result('base64').then(function(dataImg) {
                $('#imgCropped').attr('src', dataImg);

                img = document.getElementById('imgCropped');

                fetch(img.src)
                    .then(res => res.blob())
                    .then(blob => {
                        file = new File([blob], 'file', blob)
                        document.getElementById('imgtbn').file = file;
                    });
            })
        }
    });
};
```

I would like to have an input file filled with the cropped image.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Not only can you not use base64 in a file tag, but only an actual file, but you can't even set the value of a file input in Javascript at all. It's a security issue.

But why do you want to? If you've got the file encoded as base64 already, any text input is fine for sending it to the server. I'd probably use a <input type="hidden"> because it doesn't make sense to display the code. And if you want a preview, use an img tag.

Answer (score 0):

As Amunium said, file inputs are read-only.

Saving the base64 image to a hidden input is the best way to do it.

One can empty file input values programmatically, but they will still be submitted; though empty.

[There is a barebones explanation on how to get this done in a simple way](https://gist.github.com/danrydell/e083f72a4dd12bcdf2804ca7ea2e1f88).